# css text-decoration underline not working when applied to the text of an input button

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Pretty self explanatory.  I have an input button.  It has text.  It has a css class.  The css class has the attribute "text-decoration:underline;".  *The underline does not show up in firefox*.  I tried adding "!important" to the attribute but to no avail.  Apparently this is a known issue.  Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: When you say "input button", you mean a `<button>` element? You could use a `<div>` and then use JS to make it work as a button.

Comment: Correct, it is an input type=button.  Is that the only way?

Comment: Why not use the <button> element? http://jsfiddle.net/PhWEQ/

Comment: Please read the question.  The issue is that firefox will not apply text-decoration: underline.  I changed it to a button and it changed nothing.  Just like using a div.  Look at your fiddle in firefox, it does not work.

Comment: ff 9.0.1 shows the button in the fiddle underlined.

Comment: @Travis J, it works fine in all browsers (even IE). A button with the text underlined. Perhaps you have an issue with Firefox? I can provide a screen shot if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `position: absolute`, `display: block`, or `float: left` to the button. (`display: block` recommended.) Don't ask why.

You may also notice that Firefox will render the underline in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Comment: This is the answer.  I used display:inline-block.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Better way is to use `display:inline-block` it does not alter position of element.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see any problem with underlining the text in `<input type=button>` on Firefox (technically, I mean; I see many usability problems with the idea). You may have something else on your page that prevents the underlining.

On the other hand, if you wish to underline just *parts* of the text, you can use `<button>`, which lets you use markup in the text, even `<u>`.

Comment: In theory there is nothing wrong, why would there be?  However, firefox will not render the underline when the css is applied.  This is the problem which is posed.

Comment: On Firefox 9.0.1 (Win 7) `text-decoration: underline` works just fine when applied to `<input type=button>`. You need to tell more about your page so that we can see what the problem really is.