# text-decoration not working on <input type="button"> in Opera

Tags: css, opera

Given the following code:

HTML:

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Click me" />
```

CSS:

```
#myButton{
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can see this as live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ffWq/).

I want to achieve that the text inside the button is underlined. It works fine in IE9, Chrome 21, Firefox 14 and Safari 5.1.5, but it is not working in current Opera 12.

I tried the suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809790/css-text-decoration-underline-not-working-when-applied-to-the-text-of-an-input-b), but still no underlined text inside the button in Opera. How can I achieve this in that browser?

**EDIT:**

I want to use a CSS-only solution. I have a lot of forms, some of them are generated by Javascript, so it would be too much effort to change the HTML/Javascript of all these just to fix this one problem on Opera.

Comment: Reported as Opera bug CORE-18766.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<button id="test"><span>Test</span></button>
```

With the following CSS-Styles:

```
#test{ padding: 10px; }
#test span{ text-decoration: underline; }
```

Works for me in the newest Opera.

Regards 
Sören

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I want to use a CSS-only solution. I have a lot of forms, some of them are generated by Javascript, so it would be too much work to change all these and make sure that my Javascript still works everywhere. That would be too much effort just to fix this issue in Opera. I will add this to my question.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot apply text-decoration and line-through to an input type="button" under xhtml strict. It works under html 4.01 transitional, but not xhtml strict.

Comment: Changing the doctype (locally, not on the jsfiddle) to HTML 4.01 Transitional does not solve the problem. Anyway, on the page where I use this, I use HTML5 doctype, the behavior is the same.